# onclick function not working(changing style)

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I created two modals, one for login, and the other one for registering. Each one has a span which closes the modal on click, but for some reason, only the first modal is closing when i click on it.

I have tried a solution that worked, which is creating two different spans with a function for each one of them, and also extra css code, but that is a lengthy approach which i've learned is not a good practice.

JS

```
let modal = document.querySelector("#modal-login");

let modalCadastro = document.querySelector("#modal-cadastro");

let abreModal = document.querySelector(".abre-modal");

let abreModalCadastro = document.querySelector(".abre-modal-cadastro");

let fechaModal = document.querySelector(".close");





//MODAL LOGIN

abreModal.onclick = function(){

        modal.style.display = "block";

}

abreModalCadastro.onclick = function(){


        modalCadastro.style.display = "block";

}



fechaModal.onclick = function(){


    modal.style.display = "none";
    modalCadastro.style.display = "none";

}
```

HTML

```html
    <div id="modal-login">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <p>Login</p>
                    <input type="text" name="">
                    <p>Senha</p>
                    <input type="password" name="">
                    <button class="botao-entra" type="submit">Entrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="modal-cadastro">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <p>Login</p>
                    <input type="text" name="" required="required">

                    <p>E-mail</p>
                    <input type="E-mail" name="" required="required">

                    <p>Senha</p>
                    <input type="password" name="" required="required">
                    <button class="botao-entra" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: did you tried `addEventListener` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `document.querySelector` you select the first occurrence of the element you query. In your case you have two `.close` buttons. Use `document.querySelectorAll` instead to select all the elements that are found by the query.

```
let fechaModals = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
```

And then loop over each `.close` button to add the event listener.

```
fechaModals.forEach(fechaModal => {
   fechaModal.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       modal.style.display = "none";
       modalCadastro.style.display = "none";
       event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But how did fechaModal work if the variable is called fechaModals with an s at the end? And also, why the preventDefault? It worked just fine without it

Comment: Good questions. I've renamed `fechaModal` to `fechaModals` because it was selecting more than one element. So naming your variables in singular or plural can give you a good indication of what kind of value your variable is. In the `forEach` method we loop over each of the `fechaModals`. And a single one of those is called `fechaModal`. I could have named it anything what i wanted, but code should be readable and understandable first and foremost. So plural and singular. I don't know if this is correct Portugese grammar :). Boa noite!

Comment: Thank you, that clarified it all. Yes, that is correct Portuguese grammar. Good night

Comment: Also the `event.preventDefault();` is not necessary when clicking a `<span>`. But I suggest you change your HTML of `.close` elements to a `<a>` or `<button>`. This is a good practice since you will use clickable elements built in the browser. So when switching over to a `<a href="#">` or a `<button>` use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the default click behavior from happening. Without it you would navigate or scroll to a page or maybe submit a form, depending on the context of the element.

Answer (score 2):

[document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns only the first element in the document that matches the CSS selector. You can do like this:

**JS**

```js
function OpenForm(name){
  if (name === 'login') {
    document.querySelector("#modal-login").style.display = "block";
  } else if (name === 'register') {
    document.querySelector("#modal-cadastro").style.display = "block";
  }
}

function Close(name){
  if (name === 'login') {
    document.querySelector("#modal-login").style.display = "none";
  } else if(name === 'register') {
    document.querySelector("#modal-cadastro").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="modal-login">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" onclick="Close('login')">&times;</span>
        <p>Login</p>
        <input type="text" name="">
        <p>Senha</p>
        <input type="password" name="">
        <button class="botao-entra" type="submit">Entrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal-cadastro">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" onclick="Close('register')">&times;</span>
        <p>Login</p>
        <input type="text" name="" required="required">

        <p>E-mail</p>
        <input type="E-mail" name="" required="required">

        <p>Senha</p>
        <input type="password" name="" required="required">
        <button class="botao-entra" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" name="Login" class="abre-modal" onclick="OpenForm('login')">Login</button>
      <button type="button" name="Register" class="abre-modal-cadastro" onclick="OpenForm('register')">Register</button>
    </div>
```

```css
#modal-login, #modal-cadastro {
        display: none;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `document.querySelector` returns the first element that match selector. so only the first one with `.close` will work.
you have to do this with two different ids